# Already initialized constant Dir::Tmpname::UNUSABLE_CHARSError while running rails 6.1.3.1 server

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, server, rubygems

/Users/coldaustin/.rbenv/versions/3.0.0/lib/ruby/3.0.0/tmpdir.rb:118: warning: already initialized constant Dir::Tmpname::UNUSABLE_CHARS
/Users/coldaustin/.rbenv/versions/3.0.0/lib/ruby/gems/3.0.0/gems/tmpdir-0.1.2/lib/tmpdir.rb:118: warning: previous definition of UNUSABLE_CHARS was here
/Users/coldaustin/.rbenv/versions/3.0.0/lib/ruby/3.0.0/tmpdir.rb:120: warning: already initialized constant Dir::Tmpname::RANDOM
/Users/coldaustin/.rbenv/versions/3.0.0/lib/ruby/gems/3.0.0/gems/tmpdir-0.1.2/lib/tmpdir.rb:120: warning: previous definition of RANDOM was here

Comment: Just ran a gem update and started getting this error... Any solution yet?